# Is んですから/ので/... grammatically correct?

Tags: spoken-language, particle-から

I've been told by my teachers not to use んです and から/ので together, but I encounter them sometimes, both by sight and by ear. When I try to use it myself, it's always marked wrong.

For example, I am quite sure the sentence 10時半のバスに乗るんだから、早く支度しなさい。in this [link](https://www.jpf.go.jp/j/project/japanese/teach/tsushin/grammar/201009.html) would be considered incorrect by my teacher, but it's stated to be correct here.

jgram also states that [んです should never be used with other words/ constructions that also indicate reason, like から、ので、ものですから](http://www.jgram.org/pages/viewOne.php?tagE=ndesu).

Which of the following are grammatically sound?

> んですから / んだから
>
> んですので / んだので
>
> んものですから / んものだから

Comment: Actually most native can use both alike depending on the stems/roots connecting to those featured forms. They all grammatically correct because all the んs are 撥音便 (N-euphony) nasal sound change from の. So I think the tag should be 'proper N euphonic changes'

Comment: I don't think there is such a tag, but I've added spoken-language after what you said. Thanks! Euphonic changes of no to n aside, is it acceptable to use ん + です (which indicates reason already) with another construction to indicate reason?

Comment: Actually in my dialect, like in んです+から/けん form, you can often hear...it is inappropriate in JST grammar. Anyway I will attempt answering this question later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 「10時半{じはん}のバスに乗{の}るんだから、早{はや}く支度{したく}しなさい。」

This sentence would sound O.K. and even fairly natural, if not perfect, **if it were uttered by a busy mom in an informal situation**.  Grammarians might disagree here, but it is something you would actually hear native speakers say in real life.  The average speaker is not a grammarian.

If you said 「乗るから」 instead of 「乗るんだから」, then it would probably satisfy everyone.  But who speaks his native language to satisfy everyone?

Interestingly, though, it would sound 100% natural (instead of just 90% as it does now) if you switched the two clauses and uttered them as two sentences as in:

> 「早く支度しなさい！10時半のバスに乗るんだから！」

That would just wipe out the small amount of awkwardness of the original sentence above.

Moving on...

> Which of the following are grammatically sound?
>
> んですから / んだから
>
> んですので / んだので
>
> んものですから / んものだから

んですから and んだから are unquestionably sound.

んだので is sound in 飲{の}んだので, 死{し}んだので, etc. but you ***cannot*** say 「乗るんだので」.

んものですから and んものだから are simply out of the question.

Comment: Thank you for the useful information and clear reply! I think I see that んだので is usable only as part of a verb's te-form.